# Using jQuery() versus using find() method on set of matched elements?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out **how to properly use the `jQuery find()` method on an already existing matched elements set**.

I initially retrieve a set of matched elements via

```
scrollItems = $('div.topicrow-header')
```

I am using a `sticky` class to place a fixed header at top of page depending what content is currently in view.

When I detect a new element in view, I do

```
scrollItems.removeClass('stick');
$('#'+id).addClass("stick")
```

where `id` is id of element that is currently in view.

Above works, **but I really just want to only search the `scrollItems` array directly** as opposed to applying `$('#'+id)` to the entire `DOM`.

When I try

```
scrollItems.find('#'+id).addClass("stick");
```

it doesn't work. In Chrome Tools, I can see that `scrollItems` is indeed the array I expect it to be, and that it contains an element with a matching `id`, but above `find` call is not returning anything.

I have also read that you can pass a second argument to `jQuery` to limit the search context. So trying this

```
$('#'+id, scrollItems).find('#'+id).addClass("stick");
```

also doesn't work.

I have a feeling I am fundamentally not understanding some aspect of the `scrollItems` data type, and that is why things are not working as I am aiming.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery find is searching for child elements when indeed you seem to want to filter the array you already have. Use [filter-method](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
scrollItems.filter('#'+id).addClass("stick");
```